# Error installing Kubernetes on Ubuntu 22-04 with CoreDNS

Tags: ubuntu, docker, kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and I am trying to install it on an EC2 instance based on Ubuntu 22.04. Initially I was following the tutorial [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux). However, I believe it might be either misleading or outdated because at the very least, the Docker installation was giving me issues. I overcame those issues by installing Docker with [these](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository) instructions instead. With that out of the way, I ran `sudo kubeadm init` and it seemed to be working until I ran into this error: **error execution phase addon/coredns: unable to fetch CoreDNS current installed version and ConfigMap.: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = malformed header: missing HTTP content-type**. I found a similar error on the Kubernetes [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/82592) but I am not really comfortable following them until I understand why this is happening in the first place. What is CoreDNS in this context and why would a rather clean install of Kubernetes fail to "fetch" it?